# electron-builder Info.plist

Tags: electron, info.plist, electron-builder

I have an issue regarding the electron-builder module.
I need to add a custom url protocol to the mac os application I'm currently working on, and I don't understand where is the Info.plist of the app to modify it and add the CFBundleURLSchemes.

I tried creating the entitlements.mac.plist in the build folder, but after I run npm run dist it is still using the default Info.plist.

If you can help me with some references to where is the Info.plist file I should modify it would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the answer was right under my nose, you can use this call from the documentation to set your custom protocol:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-macos-windows

Comment: Hi Bogdan, could you please tell me where you put the CFBundleURLSchemes? If it was in the info.plist, where you put that file or how you refer that?